# Im an amateur depelover, where can i share my small tricks for elementary os loki?

Tags: release-loki, desktop

I have said all in the title, I have programed a few scripts in perl to personalize the desktop a bit, and I'd like to share it with others because isn't enough programs to do this stuff.

Comment: Care to share a link to your stuff? I'd like to check them out.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider building apps for the App Center. If you have scripts you'd like to share you can share them on GitHub Gist. I have an elementary install script on there and it's saved me a ton of time.

Check out the [Getting Started](https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#gtk-application) guide written by the elementary developers. Also check out Egee's [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxvZGf69nko) on getting started with GTK & Vala development in elementary.

Comment: Care to share a link to your stuff? I'd like to check them out.

Comment: I don't have much in the way of elementary apps, but a lot of my work and partial work is on github: https://github.com/PretzelJones?tab=repositories I also have som scripts for elementary on github gist https://gist.github.com/PretzelJones